# Trying to relocate a drain- I need to deviate like 27 degrees from the original direction of the drain. What are my options?

Tags: plumbing

I have had a busy time at work and I am now getting back to my bathroom renovation project
The picture below shows what I am trying to do
I would like to avoid digging out the pipe and cutting out the concrete to the right of the picture
Ideally I would like to join the existing and the new drain pipe near the right edge of the opening you see in the picture. What options do I have ? I do not like the flex connectors I do not think it is a good idea to leave then under ground. Just to be clear  am installing a shower base there and relocating the sink drain

[image]

Here is the overall plan for the plumbing for this section of my project, The angles we are talking about are not exactly rendered in the diagram below

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a 22-1/2 degree elbow and flex the pipe if they won’t do it because of the short space a fernco or no hub in the middle will give a couple degrees they are not designed to be flexed but a slight couple of degrees will work if you can’t make a small bend with heat a hair dryer may be enough with abs to get the extra bend if you don’t want to use a fernco. I would never use the corrugated flex pipe and especially not under a slab. But the elbow and a bit of bend in the pipe should do it.

Comment: I think that I will go the 22 1/2 route, by flex I meant fernco, the metal will rust and it will end up leaking

Comment: I totally forgot about the 22 1/2 elbow which probably will save my life here
I need to play with the angles a little to see what is the optimum location 
I guess I will take a couple of elbows from HD and find the optimum geometry for this
Are there any code restrictions in regards to how many and how close they can be from the other elements of the piping scheme posted above ?

Comment: The rubber will last decades by the time the metal rusts out if it ever dose the earth will be packed around it some don’t have the metal and the hose clamps are stainless I put these on my moms septic line over 40 years ago and they are still intact but the 22-1/2 are better if you can flex the pipe a little.